# Generate XML in specific format from struct

Tags: xml, go

I Need to generate this xml from a structure:

```
<doc>
    <item name='documentCommand' value='i' />
    <item name='documentType' value='1' />
    <item name='offset' value='0' />
    <item name='bytesRead' value='63636' />
    <item name='bDoneUpload' value='false' />
    <item name='documentVar' value='' />
    <item name='vendorFileName' value='/example.pdf' />
</doc>
```

I have the following structure:

```
type XMLDoc struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name `xml:"doc"`
    DocumentCommand string   `xml:"documentCommand"`
    DocumentType    string   `xml:"documentType"`
    Offset          string   `xml:"offset"`
    BytesRead       string   `xml:"bytesRead"`
    DoneUpload      string   `xml:"bDoneUpload"`
    DocumentVar     string   `xml:"documentVar"`
    FileName        string   `xml:"vendorFileName"`
}
```

Using xml.Marshal gives me this and it is not acceptable to the endpoint:

```
<doc>
    <documentCommand>i</documentCommand>
    <documentType>27</documentType>
    <offset>27181</offset>
    <bytesRead>0</bytesRead>
    <bDoneUpload>true</bDoneUpload>
    <documentVar></documentVar>
    <vendorFileName>testdoc.pdf</vendorFileName>
</doc>
```

Then endpoint tells me the bDoneUpload string boolean is not valid.

What is the proper way to create the desired XML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that specific order for your XML `item`'s then you could use a slice like so:

```
type XMLDoc struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"doc"`
    Items   []Item   `xml:"item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}
```

and to use:

```
v := XMLDoc{
    Items: []Item{
        Item{"documentCommand", "i"},
        Item{"documentType", "1"},
        /* ... */
    },
}
```

Playground [working example](https://play.golang.org/p/B88tQ4rb08Q).

---

You could also create a custom [XML Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) to render the XML exactly how you would like e.g.

```
type XMLDoc struct {
    Comment    string
    Type       string
    Offset     int
    Read       int
    DoneUpload bool
    Var        string
    VenderPath string
}

func (x XMLDoc) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) (err error) { /* ... */ }
```

- Pro: one can use native go-types like `int`, `bool` etc. for fields
- Con: Marshaler can be tedious to write: https://play.golang.org/p/KZ-HKgNHmbE